# Maximum number of edges in unconnected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

In an undirected graph with `n` vertices and no edges, what is the maximum number of edges that can be added so that the graph remains unconnected? This is an interview question.

1. NC2
2. (N-1)C2
3. N!
4. (N-1)!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an interview question that does not relate to programming.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum number of edges in a graph with N vertices is NC2 ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61579/how-can-i-prove-the-maximum-number-of-edges)).

Note that, to remain unconnected, one of the vertices should not have any edges. More formally, there has to be [a cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory)) (across which there won't be any edges) with one side having only one vertex. Why not more than one vertex? Proof by induction:

The cases for 0, 1 and 2 vertices are trivial.

Consider a graph with 3 vertices. The best cut will be one with 2 vertices on one side and 1 vertex on the other side.

Now assume the best cut is one with N-1 vertices on one side and 1 vertex on the other with N >= 3. Now try to add a vertex. Adding the vertex to the side with one vertex will result in one edge that can be added. Adding the vertex to the other side will result in N-1 possible edges. Clearly N-1 > 1 for N >= 3. Thus it's always better to add the vertex to the side with N-1 vertices.

Now there are two ways to go from here:

1. Consider the graph without one of the edges. The maximum number of edges of this sub-graph is `(N-1)C2`.
2. Consider the maximum number of edges of the graph as is and subtract the number of edges from one vertex. This gives `NC2 - (N-1)` = `N(N-1)/2 - 2(N-1)/2` = `(N-2)(N-1)/2` = `(N-1)C2`.

So the answer is `(N-1)C2`, i.e. option 2.

Answer (score 0):

b (n-1)C2

An example of such a graph is a complete graph of n-1 vertices and one isolated vertex.

In this example, the complement graph would have nC2 - (n-1)C2 = n-1 edges.
And either given graph or its complement is connected ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122184/given-a-simple-graph-and-its-complement-prove-that-either-of-them-is-always-con)).
Hence, if we constucted a graph with more than (n-1)C2 edges, then the complement would have less than n-1 edges and couldn't be connected, so our graph would be.